# The Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am trying to expand $f(z)=\frac{1}{e^z-1}$ in Laurent series.

One approach I tried involved writing $f(z)=e^{-z} \frac{1}{1-e^{-z}}$, expanding the fraction as a geometric series: $1+e^{-z}+e^{-2z}+ \cdots$ to get $f(z)=e^{-z}+e^{-2z}+ \cdots$. At this point, I think I can expand all of the terms as a series, and try to add the series term by term. I am not sure if this is a reasonable approach. What would be a reasonable approach?

Comment: I assume that you want the Laurent series converging in $0 < \lvert z\rvert < 2\pi$. Make the ansatz $$\frac{z}{e^z-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_n}{n!}z^n$$ and find a recurrence for the coefficients by multiplying $$z = \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{c_n}{n!}z^n\right)\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}z^k.$$ Then divide by $z$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Shouldn't the ansatz start at $n=-1$?

Comment: @GitGud Oops. (Thanks, by the way.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach won't work, because the term-by-term series you get won't converge. In particular, $e^{-kz}=1$ for $z=0$ regardless of the value of $k$, so the sum of your constant terms is divergent.

I suggest noticing that, as $f$ has a simple pole at the origin, the function $zf(z)=\frac{z}{e^z-1}$ has a removable singularity and hence is legitimately Taylor-expandable. Having so noticed, you might want to read up on [Bernoulli numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliNumber.html).